# Show that $\Phi_\epsilon(x-a)\cdot\Phi_\epsilon(b-x)$ converges to an index function $I\{a\le x\le b\}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

Let 
$$f(x)=I\{a\le x\le b\}$$
and
$$f_\epsilon(x)=\Phi_\epsilon(x-a)\cdot\Phi_\epsilon(b-x),$$
where $\Phi_\epsilon(z)$ is the normal cumulative distribution with mean zero and variance $\epsilon^2$. Then as $\epsilon\to0$,
$$f_\epsilon(x)\to f(x).$$

Is the above stamtement correct and how to prove it?

Comment: What do you mean by $\to$?

Comment: It means "converge to".

Comment: I understand the high level meaning, but for random variables there are many notions of convergence. I was asking which one you mean.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity of notation. It is just the convergence for ordinary function. Expect the normal distribution, there is no random variable convergence here.

Comment: Note that $\Phi_\epsilon(0) = {1 \over 2}$, so it does not converge to $1_{[a,b]}$ at $a,b$.

Comment: I come up with a solution below. Hope that you can give some comments.

Answer (score 0):

When mean=variance=$0$, normal distribution degenerates into single point distribtution, that is, $\Phi_\epsilon(x-a)\to I\{x\ge a\}$ and $\Phi_\epsilon(b-x)\to I\{b\ge x\}$, as $\epsilon\to0$. So
$$\Phi_\epsilon(x-a)\cdot\Phi_\epsilon(b-x)\to I\{x\ge a\}\cdot  I\{b\ge x\}=I\{a\le x\le b\}.$$

Comment: Did you read my last comment on the question?

Comment: You are right. What about $x\neq a,b$?